# need to compare ip addresses

Tags: php, mysqli

i have this container with users ip

```
$forum['User']['ipaddress'];
```

i have table **threads** and 2 columns in phpMyAdmin **pid** (thread id) and **ipaddress** (user comment ip)

if user has written 2 posts in a one forum thread need to display a message `<p> Your ip repeated </ p>`

[image]

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "db");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
```

how can i do this ?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how can i show this message ? better watch

Comment: You could `COUNT` the rows that have *both* the user's IP and the thread id.

Comment: i know, i need help with code

Comment: Please google and try something for yourself before asking the community to do the work for you. Look into mysql querying in php, PDO, and some frontend stuff like javascript and html. I have flagged this question as too broad

Comment: I send an answer, but as others have said, don't try to build something quickly by copy pasting code. Try to understand the logic by building it step by step (learning to grabbing all the data, learning to cound the data etc..). You won't learn by copy pasting data. If you apply this logic here, you will learn to quickly use it in any language.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for.
I haven't tested this code as it's not easy, but you should get the idea.

```
//escaping to prevent sql injection
$pid = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $post_id);
$ipaddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $forum['User']['ipaddress']);

$query = "SELECT count(ipaddress) AS addresses_found FROM threads WHERE ipaddress = {$ipaddress} AND pid = {$pid}";

$count_ip_addresses = 0;
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
  $count_ip_addresses = $row['addresses_found']

  $result->free();
}

if($count_ip_addresses >= 2){
  echo '<p> Your ip repeated </ p>';
}
```